# Samrt gwt hidden textitem issue with panel colapsing

Tags: smartgwt

I have some GWT components(textitem) which are hidden for some customers. The probelm is when collapsing and  expanding the panel  some time those hidden fields can be seen and seem they initialize for panle event removeing hiiden proprty. Could some one explain why exactly this happen.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If they are always hidden just instance HiddenItem instead TextItem.